# Word for "Ready/want to go home"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

In Mormon missionary culture, they use the word "trunky" to describe the feeling at the end of their two-year mission when they are tired, ready to go home, and are mentally packing their trunks to go home.  They have mentally checked out from their mission at hand.

I'm looking for a commonly used word or phrase that means generally the same thing as "trunky".

Comment: I expect you'll find there isn't one, which is the very reason why those Mormon missionaries found it necessary to coin a usage based on alluding to *"I'm ready to pack my **trunk** and leave"*.

Comment: I agree with @fumblefingers, now that I think about it. For what it's worth, I like this "trunky" idea, and may start using it.

Comment: If you look at the etymology of nostalgia, you'll find an uncommonly used word for it.  http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=nostalgia&allowed_in_frame=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US Military one common term was [FIGMO](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=figmo), politely it meant "Forget It, Got My Orders", I'll leave it to you & Google to figure out what it really meant.  Another term was "[DEROS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_Eligible_for_Return_from_Overseas)" meaning Date Eligible for Return from Overseas, the date when you'd leave to go home.  It's worth a Google as well if for nothing else the trench art.  You'll find that there'll be a count of days "and a wake up" with some very um..colorful calendars, but I digress.

A term I've heard in the Pacific Northwest is "dundy" (done-dee?) not sure of the spelling, I've never seen it in print.  It means you're done, finished, ready to go home, usually in a "I'm sick & tired of this" connotation.  In Hawaii, you'll hear ["All pau now" or "pau hana"](http://www.eyeofhawaii.com/Pidgin/pidgin.htm) which generally means "we're done doing whatever it was we were doing, let's go home/ get a drink".

In Malay, you will hear: "[sudah](http://mymemory.translated.net/t/Malay/English/sudah)?" as in "done already?".  And in Hainanese you might hear: "ho mei?" which is nearly identical in meaning to "sudah" at least to this gwai-lo's ear (my wife is Malaysian & ethnically Chinese).

Comment: Added some links per your request, as well as a couple more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "cashed," "fried," "spent," "running on empty" or simply "done" in that context.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase from military life ***short-timer*** has come into common parlance. Sometimes, it is linked to attitude, as ***short-timer's attitude***. The idea is of someone who is near the end of an assignment and is at least mentally already shifting into whatever will come next.

> short-timer    Use Short-timer in a sentence
>
> short-tim·er  [shawrt-tahy-mer] Show IPA
>
> noun Informal.  a person, as a soldier, who has a short period of time
>   left to serve on a tour of duty.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/short-timer